# Nextjs custom script is loaded but not being excuted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to load a custom script like so :

```
<Script
    src="url/embed.js"
    strategy="beforeInteractive"
/>
```

I also have tried it with afterInteractive and lazyOnload
the script gets loaded

```
Richiedi URL: url/embed.js
Metodo di richiesta: GET
Codice di stato: 200
```

But i guess it never gets executed. It should load a video

```
<div class="video-container" data-embed="xxxxx" data-customer="xxxx" data-nfs="xxxx" data-width="720" data-height="405" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
```

But in a normal page this, it works perfectly like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="url/embed.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div
        class="video-container"
        data-embed="xxxx"
        data-customer="xxxx"
        data-nfs="xxxx"
        data-width="720"
        data-height="405"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But in nextjs it dosent work

Comment: Is <Script> component inside <Head> ?

Comment: @Tushar no it's outside. I've read that it should be outside. am i right?